# How do I replay the Max Payne 3 intro?

Tags: max-payne-3

I want to watch the Max Payne 3 intro in 1920x1080 AND subtitled. How do I replay it?

Deleting the "Profiles" folder only partially solves my problem, since the graphic settings are stored in graphics.xml which is untouched when I delete the folder.

Unfortunately the setting for subtitles enabled are stored in the "Profiles" folder I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the mp3_progression file in my documents\rockstar games\ max payne 3\ "profile name"

Answer (score 1):

Although this option doesn't let you watch with subtitles its a general answer that should work for most games out there.

Download [Rad Video Tools](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm). With this you can watch video files with the `.bik` file extension (which is what a lot of games use). For Max Payne 3 you should find the movie files in MAX_PAYNE3_INSTALLATION/common/movies.